# JavaScript - If mouseover on the parent then effect on child

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to display a div with some text within some boxes when the mouse is on the box.

My problem is that the box container `.card-indus` contain the title `.card-header` and the text to toggle `.text-image`. So I want to display the `.text-image` from `none` to `flex` whenever the user in on the parent box of that text-image. How can I do that?

[without text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvaNv.jpg)
[with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI3lH.jpg)

thank you!

**HTML**

```
            <div class="card-indus">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p>Digital</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <img src="../images/services/digital.jpeg">
                    <p class="text-image">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptatibus numquam eveniet doloremque dignissimos veniam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-indus">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p>Healthcare</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <img src="../images/services/healthcare.jpg">
                    <p class="text-image">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptatibus numquam eveniet doloremque dignissimos veniam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-indus">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p>Industry</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <img src="../images/services/industry.jpg">
                    <p class="text-image">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptatibus numquam eveniet doloremque dignissimos veniam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.industries .container-industries .card-indus {
  position: relative;
  border: red solid 1px;
  color: white;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.industries .container-industries .card-indus img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

}

.industries .container-industries .card-indus .text-image {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using simple css

```
.industries .container-industries .card-indus:hover .text-image {
  display: flex;
}
```

You can move the `:hover` selector on the class you want if I misunderstood where you wanted it :)

Comment: Yes, much more easier! thanks. Seems we can also do everything with CSS rather than with JS? Do you any counter example in mind?

Comment: There some limitations to css selectors, if the div you hover wasn't a direct parent it could be impossible to do this with css. However whenever you can it's always better to use css from a performance point of vue.

Answer (score 1):

@Morphyish's answer is excellent, however I would mention that if you toggle visibility by *opacity* instead of display you can use a css transition for a nice animation/fade-in effect:

```css
  .industries .container-industries .card-indus .text-image {
      display: flex; /** display flex by default **/
      position: absolute;
      color: red;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0; /** Makes the text invisible **/
      transition: .2s ease-in opacity; /** Sets how quickly the "opacity" value will transition  **/
    }

    .industries .container-industries .card-indus:hover .text-image {
      opacity: 1; /** Sets opacity to full on hover! **/ 
    }
```